# VB- number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: database, vb.net

I seriously can't see any problem here.  But I get the error

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data/Database5.mdb"))
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES (@firstName, @lastName)"
        Dim txtFname As New TextBox
        Dim txtLname As New TextBox
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtLname.Text)
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
```

Database: Id; autonumber
          firstName; text
          lastName; text

Comment: (  Id + firstName + lastName) = 3 ; but you are only passing 2 params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your SQL:

`INSERT INTO Users (firstName,lastName) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName)`

Comment: Thank you, that was bad on my part. While I got you, once the data is entered in the database, a new ID is created however the firstname and lastname isn't recorded. Any ideas to why? Thank you

Comment: Why are you creating two text boxes in that method? Your query parameters will always have a blank value because you're referring textboxes you just instantiated.

Comment: Agreed. Since you're creating the textboxes on the fly, they have no value. Put then on your form or asp page (whichever applies) and then read the value from them in code.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comment I made, it's best to employ Using blocks for disposable resources such as connections and commands. Also note the absence of the two TextBoxes you were creating.

```
Using conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data/Database5.mdb"))
    conn.Open()
    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName)", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFname.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtLname.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Wow, yea this is better. And man am I tired not to notice such mistakes....sorry still a learner. But thanks a lot!